# Constant linker errors when compiling a program using Dear ImGui

Tags: c++, visual-c++

83

Back-ends: imgui_impl_dx9.cpp + imgui_impl_win32.cpp
Operating System: Windows 10 
Compiler: Visual Studio 2019

**My Issue/Question:**

I keep getting constant linker errors when trying to compile my program and I cannot figure out what is causing them
I have the files required and they're included in the .sln properties and in my main.cpp

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>ConsoleApplication2.cpp
1>imgui_widgets.cpp
1>Generating Code...
1>ConsoleApplication2.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _Direct3DCreate9@4 referenced in function "bool __cdecl CreateDeviceD3D(struct HWND__ *)" (?CreateDeviceD3D@@YA_NPAUHWND__@@@Z)
1>imgui_impl_win32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _XInputGetState@8 referenced in function "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplWin32_UpdateGamepads(void)" (?ImGui_ImplWin32_UpdateGamepads@@YAXXZ)
1>imgui_impl_win32.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _XInputGetCapabilities@12 referenced in function "void __cdecl ImGui_ImplWin32_UpdateGamepads(void)" (?ImGui_ImplWin32_UpdateGamepads@@YAXXZ)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x64\xinput.lib : warning LNK4272: library machine type 'x64' conflicts with target machine type 'x86'
1>C:\Users\Logan\source\repos\ConsoleApplication2\Debug\ConsoleApplication2.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "ConsoleApplication2.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Link with the required library see the __Requirements__ section - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d3d9/nf-d3d9-direct3dcreate9

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)